# HTTP Post Error C# Contact page

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, smtp, contact-form

I've created an MVC project where i'm trying to build a contact page and i'm having an issue with my HTTP Post. Basically, when it is included I get a page not found error on for the page(before submitting the form etc), when it is not included there is no problems.
All help is appreciated

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactModels c)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress(c.Email.ToString());
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                msg.To.Add("ag@gmail.com");
                msg.Subject = "Contact";
                msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
                client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                client.Port = 587;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your gmail email address", "your gmail email address password");
                sb.Append("First Name: " + c.FirstName);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append("last Name: " + c.LastName);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append("Email: " + c.Email);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append("Comments: " + c.Comment);

                msg.Body = sb.ToString();
                client.Send(msg);
                msg.Dispose();
                return View("Success");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }



        }
        return View();
    }
```

EDIT: Error Message
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Home/Contact

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.114.0

Comment: *"I would be grateful if someone could point me in the direction of a good dummy Smtp server to test this properly"* Create a gmail account for testing, its free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're getting the page not found error before you submit the form, meaning when you're loading the form?  If that is the case, I think the problem is because when you mark your action as post it will not run with a get request.  The request to load the form would be a get request.

Please try creating a second action that returns the view but accepts get requests.

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    return View();  // probably don't need to do much of anything here other than return the view with the form.
}
```

This will handle the get request that will display the form, then your existing Action will handle the post of the form.

Comment: Done it!!!! Didn't need the 'get' request but a separate controller did the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this
client.enablessl = true;
client.port = 465;

Comment: Tried it, same issues. Thanks anyway